# Advanced Bootstrap Grid Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently building a layout for a project using (Bootstrap)[http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/]. It appears the way I want it to, but the content in the `"username"` section **overflows** into the section below. The **text becomes hidden** but it can still be selected, it is there and I am worried it will glitch on mobile.

There is any other way to make a layout like this. Does anyone have an example of something similar, or could someone please help me fix this and make it better, as it does not work on phone size view ports correctly.

Thank you in advance,

### Chris.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h3>Welcome</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8" style="height:250px;">
    <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <h5>Your Projects:</h5>
        <div class="project-container" style="display: inline;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="height:250px;background-color:#fff">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <h3 style="float: right;">username</h3>
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">Other user data here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8" style="height:500px;">
    <div class="row" style="height:50%;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <h5>Pinned Projects:</h5>
        <div class="project-container" style="display: inline;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h5>Trending Projects:</h5>
        <div class="project-container" style="display: inline;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="height:500px;background-color:#fff">
    <h3>Recent Activity</h3>
    <br>
    <p>Other user data here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ac nisl eget nisi hendrerit ullamcorper nec vitae eros. Cras pellentesque blandit malesuada. Sed lobortis accumsan varius. Morbi vulputate dolor felis, non iaculis
      ex pellentesque vel. Aenean consectetur, augue aliquet auctor imperdiet, lectus enim accumsan metus, et dapibus elit eros eget risus. Aenean eu cursus lacus. Nam condimentum tellus in diam lacinia iaculis. Morbi vitae libero dolor. Maecenas tempus
      eleifend mauris, eu porttitor nisi lobortis at. In molestie eros at felis cursus egestas. Nunc a tincidunt dolor. Duis sem elit, consequat sed facilisis non, lobortis in arcu.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Chris, I think we also need your CSS implementation if there one. That will help us to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Chris, where do you want to put the username? By the way, it is float right. If you want, just remove it.

Comment: @Teocci I am using bootstrap. That is all my CSS inline. I merged it so I did not have to add another file.

Comment: @smzvax That is where I want the username, I have to have the float right other wise it goes below the image. That is not the point of my question though. if I add a paragraph of data below the username, it overflows into the recent activity section. also it all breaks on mobile viewport size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is a modified implementation of your layout that fixes the 'username','recent activity' and 'trending projects' position by removing some unnecessary rows and columns and encapsulates the grid in a container, following bootstrap convention.

It could be useful to explore the docs: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <div class='container'>
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8" style="height:250px;">
            <h5>Your Projects:</h5>
            <div class="project-container" style="display: inline;">
              <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
              <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
              <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
              <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
              <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4" style="height:250px;background-color:#fff">
              <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100">
              <h3>username</h3>
              <p style="overflow: hidden;">Other user data here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h5>Pinned Projects:</h5>
                <div class="project-container" style="display: inline;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#fff">
              <h3>Recent Activity</h3>
              <br>
              <p>Other user data here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                  Vivamus ac nisl eget nisi hendrerit ullamcorper nec vitae eros. Cras pellentesque blandit malesuada. Sed
                  lobortis accumsan varius. Morbi vulputate dolor felis, non iaculis ex pellentesque vel. Aenean
                  consectetur, augue aliquet auctor imperdiet, lectus enim accumsan metus, et dapibus elit eros eget
                  risus. Aenean eu cursus lacus. Nam condimentum tellus in diam lacinia iaculis. Morbi vitae libero dolor.
                  Maecenas tempus eleifend mauris, eu porttitor nisi lobortis at. In molestie eros at felis cursus
                  egestas. Nunc a tincidunt dolor. Duis sem elit, consequat sed facilisis non, lobortis in arcu.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h5>Trending Projects:</h5>
                <div class="project-container" style="display: inline;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to fix the trending projects section, it displays in a block instead of  inline like the "pinned" and "trending" projects sections.

Comment: Done, check it again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `"Your Project"` section you are using this:

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="height:250px;">
```

Therefore, the maximum height will be 250px I suggest you to change it to `100%` and add a padding as in this example:

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="height:100%; padding-bottom: 10px;">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h3>Welcome</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8" style="height:100%; padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <h5>Your Projects:</h5>
        <div class="project-container" style="display: inline;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="height:250px;background-color:#fff">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <h3 style="float: right;">username</h3>
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">Other user data here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8" style="height:500px;">
    <div class="row" style="height:50%;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <h5>Pinned Projects:</h5>
        <div class="project-container" style="display: inline;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h5>Trending Projects:</h5>
        <div class="project-container" style="display: inline;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100" style="margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="height:500px;background-color:#fff">
    <h3>Recent Activity</h3>
    <br>
    <p>Other user data here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ac nisl eget nisi hendrerit ullamcorper nec vitae eros. Cras pellentesque blandit malesuada. Sed lobortis accumsan varius. Morbi vulputate dolor felis, non iaculis
      ex pellentesque vel. Aenean consectetur, augue aliquet auctor imperdiet, lectus enim accumsan metus, et dapibus elit eros eget risus. Aenean eu cursus lacus. Nam condimentum tellus in diam lacinia iaculis. Morbi vitae libero dolor. Maecenas tempus
      eleifend mauris, eu porttitor nisi lobortis at. In molestie eros at felis cursus egestas. Nunc a tincidunt dolor. Duis sem elit, consequat sed facilisis non, lobortis in arcu.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not see what that fixed. It appears the same to me. In mobile viewport sizes, everything becomes jumbled, but I am using a different page for mobile. Is there anyway to fix the trending projects section, it displays the items in a block shape instead of inline, like "pinned" and "your" projects.